# Javascript nested function is not worked

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects

I do not understand why the feature does not work , I passed into the method foreach.

```
 var methods = {
            foreach: function(f){
                for(var i = 0; i <= this.x; i++){
                    f(i);
                }
            }
        };
        function test(x) {
           var t = Object.create(methods);
           t.x = x;
           return t;
        };
        var t = test(10);
        console.log(t.x); //10
        t.foreach(console.log()); //Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function
```

Thx!

Comment: t.foreach(console.log); //Uncaught TypeError: Illegal invocation

Comment: t.foreach(function(x){console.log(x)}); //1 2 3 ...
Thx!

Comment: Thank you all ! This wrong example I saw in a book by David Flanagan: Javascript Pocket reference 3rd (page number 136) I did not think that there may be errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are passing **the return value** of calling `console.log()`, which isn't a function.

You need to pass an actual function.

Since `log` only works in the context of `console` you can't just pass `console.log` but you could, for instance:

```
 t.foreach(function (logthis) { console.log(logthis); });
```